# Writing a Replace Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need some help writing a regex. I have the following strings,

```
xxx.yyy.wwwwwaaa_IN_123                
xxx.rrrttttt_IN_12355                  
zz.iiiiolll_IN_12                         
xxx.zzzz.rrrr.yyy.wwwwwwww_IN_1232
```

Using Regex.Replace, I want to change the string from the above format to something like

`"$1($2)"` where `$2` would be the number at the end of the string and `$1` would be the first three letters of the last substring before the `_IN_` mark.

In another words,

```
xxx.yyy.wwwwwaaa_IN_123                www(123)
xxx.rrrttttt_IN_12355                  rrr(12355)
iiiiolll_IN_12                         iii(12)
xxx.zzzz.rrrr.yyy.wwwwwwww_IN_1232     www(1232)
```

This is what i have,

```
".*.([^\.]{3})[^\.]_IN_+([0-9]+)"
```

but this only takes the last letters before the `_IN_` mark, and not the first letters of the last substring.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this _have_ to be a Regex? Looks like something that can be done with `string.Split` and `string.Format`.

Comment: Yes, the use of regex is a limitation :(

Comment: What is `.*.([^\.]{3})[^\.]` supposed to mean?

Comment: Nope, custom framework limitation. this is for a query parser that can take a regex.

Comment: (^|\.)(.{3})[^_]*_IN_([0-9]+) -- $2($3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick, the non-greedy parts makes it not capture to much...

```
Regex.Match(input, @"(?:.*?\.)?(.{3})[^.]*?_IN_(\d+)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the right regex is:

```
Regex r = new Regex("([a-z]{3})[a-z]*_IN_(\d+)");
```

You might need a RegexOptions.IgnoreCase in case there might be upper case letters.
If you the regex is defined as a static member you might consider using RegexOptions.Compiled.

The above Regex will match bbb(123) in the string aaa_bbbbbb_IN_123.
The answer made by L.B would match aaa. 
The answer made by Frederik C will not match because there is no "." (like your 3rd example)

Comment: You are right about LB's regex. On the other hand, yours is not taking into account the dots. I've updated the example to always show at least two dots, thus the Fredrik's one was the correct. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: I cannot see why the dots are important, my regex works with or without the dots making it more accurate, flexible, faster and easier to read - It is you choice.